# How to read secrets from Key Vault without using Service Principle in Python Scripts

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-keyvault, azure-batch

We are running Python scripts in Azure Data Factory using Batch Service of Azure Data Factory.
We are reading secrets from key vault using Service Principle for which we need to hardcode the Client Id, Client Secret which has the access to read secret values.
Is there any way to overcome this problem so that there is no requirement of hardcoding the Service Principle.
Can we use Managed Identities in this case?

We tried using Managed Identities and we created a User Managed identity to access the key vault.
The Batch Account and Azure Data Factory has been provided the access to this User Managed Identity.
But we are unable to find the next steps in the same case.

We have User-Assigned managed identity which has been associated to both Data Factory and Batch Account and this Managed Identity has Secret read permissions as well.
[image]

Running the below python script to read the Secrets.

[image]

But the issue now we are facing is defined below:
[image]

The managed identity has the following associated resources :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we are developing Azure Batch Account and deploying pools in the Batch Account the created Managed Identity should have Secrets Read permissions.

The Managed Identity should be associated to the below mentioned resources in this case .

1. Azure Data Factory
2. Azure Batch Account
   **3. Pool developed under Batch Account**

We were not associating Managed Identity to the pool created and was facing this error.
The below Python Script worked for me.
[image]

Thanks

Comment: For [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2530121), please do not post images of code. Instead, copy your code into a codeblock. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials.
Attempted credentials:
    EnvironmentCredential: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.
Visit https://aka.ms/azsdk/python/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot to troubleshoot this issue.
    ManagedIdentityCredential: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable
```

Managed identity doesn't have permission to get the secret; that may be the reason for the error above. Give the required permission to the managed identity in Key Vault by following the procedure below:

Create an access policy in Key Vault as follows:

Go to access policies in Key Vault, click on `Create`, select the permissions and the identity, and then click on `Review+create`, as shown below:

[image]

After creating the access policy, you will be able to get the secret from Key Vault successfully using the code below:

```py
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient  
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential, AzureCliCredential

keyvault_credential = AzureCliCredential()
secret_client = SecretClient("https://aksvs.vault.azure.net", keyvault_credential)  
secret = secret_client.get_secret("secret")
print(secret.name)  
print(secret.value)
```

[image]

Comment: Hello
Thanks for your response. The managed identity has the access to GET, LIST secrets from key vault.
and after deploying the above Python Script in ADF executing it. Now the following error has occured.

ERROR : 

AzureCliCredential.get_token failed: Please run 'az login' to set up an account.

subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmd', '/c', 'az account get-access-token --output json --resource https://vault.azure.net --tenant dbd61555-f8c0-4db8-83e3-d55f7565507d']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Comment: when you are deploying the script with ADF you need to give permissions to ADF managed identity in key vault. make sure you have given permission.

Comment: It has the permissions to ADF as well 

In the assocaiated Resources field in Managed Identity we are able to see two resources.
1. Azure Data Factory
2. Azure Batch Account

The identity has all the permissions

but now the error is saying something as mentioned above.